# Какую частицу употребить: НИ или НЕ?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Лично у меня свои правила - отвечать только за свои слова, и кто бы себя как НИ - (НЕ) опускал - не считать себя вправе опускаться туда же.

Какую частицу употребить?

Answer (score 4):

Это уступительный союз КАК НИ (где ни, как ни, кто ни, когда ни и т.д.) в уступительном придаточном предложении, следовательно, НИ.

Answer (score 1):

Рассуждайте, что у Вас делает частица - усиливает глагол или отрицает действие, отображённое глаголом?

Если некто себя НЕ опускал, зачем нам себя с ним сравнивать?

Так что отрицание отменяется, остаётся усиление.